# How to open CSV file with Russian Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, locale

Comma is used as decimal separator in Russian locale. This is probably the reason, why Russian Excel is unable to open CSV files:

[image]

As you see, all data went to first column.

Comment: For being a Russian version, the button labels look quite anglosaxic to me?

Answer (score 2):

Open excel then
`File` -> `Open`

The `Open dialog box` appears. Change file type to `*.txt` or `*csv` in the `Files of type list`.

Excel starts the `Import Text Wizard`.

Follow the instructions in the Import Wizard.

Set radio button to "**Delimited**".

[image]

Hit the `Next` button and set **Comma** check-box

[image]

Hit `Next` and finally `Finish` button.

**EDIT:** My version of Excel does not open csv, but if I change file extension to .txt - it's works.

Answer (score 0):

Opening .csv documents in Excel is dependend on the Regional settings in windows.

A .csv document can have multiple layouts, and this is where the problem comes from.

For example, it can be "value";"value";... or "value","value", or even value,value,... or value;value;... Then of course there is the possibility of separating the values with a {tab} character.

I always use Excel, create an empty worksheet, then save this file as .csv document. Then I open the .csv document with notepad and see what the correct formatting is. I then edit the original document with notepad and search/replace whatever I need to fix the issue.

Note that Notepad++ can do this easier using \t to replace tabs.